# Paypal preapproval payments

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I see that there are lots of types in Paypal payments api. I am confused that which payment api comes under Paypal's preapproval payments. I have used Paypal's chained payment api and recurring payments api in one of the project.

Does anyone knows which payment api comes under preapproval.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preapproval comes under the `Adaptive Payments API`

A couple of Links for reference:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/